# How to get tinymce interface to appear in thymeleaf form textarea?

Tags: javascript, java, html, tinymce, thymeleaf

So this is a weird problem and, after a ton of research online, I don't think I've seen anything that solves it.

I have a form in thymeleaf. I also have tinyMCE plugin installed on the page. Does anyone know how to have the tinymce plugin show up as the input for the form?

```html
<head>
        <title>Nobody Can Solve This.</title>
         <script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
  });
  </script>

</head>
 
 <body>

  <center><h2>Submitting a post(via Tiny MCE)</h2></center>

  <form method="post">
    <textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
  </form>
 
    
   <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/blogposts/addBlogPost}" th:object="${blogPost}" method="post">
        <p>Title: <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" /></p>
        <p>Author: <input type="text" th:field="*{authors}" /></p>
        <p>Content: <input type="textarea" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
        <p><textarea name="ephox">Blog Post</textarea></p>
        <p>Subject: <input type="text" th:field="*{Subject}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
```

As you can see, I can get the TinyMCE plugin appearing on the page and even within the form, but I can't get it to actually be used to submit content.

Any ideas? I have tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not trying to come off as rude here, but Stack Overflow has been *very* disappointing when it comes to Thymeleaf Questions. People usually just direct me to the basic documentation that does not at all address my question, and assume I didn't read it. I'm not just talking about this question, but the litany of questions that I posted up and eventually deleted months later because the answers were either useless or hostile. I cannot think of more informative or descriptive ways to explain my problems than what I have in the past. Unlike this question, I typically explain everything I tried and what resources I used, only to get the exact same treatment. Is Thymeleaf just super new? Why does nobody know about it?

Anyway, the way to fix this problem is that you input a text area **below** the content input yet still within the form:

```html
 <p>Content: <input type="hidden" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
 <textarea name="object" id="object" th:field="*{content}">
```

Once properly integrated, TinyMCE will identify textareas within the .html document and apply the plugin. However, it won't do so if you just use 'input type="textarea" ' within the form. So what you're basically going to end up doing instead is creating a different text area below the input component and ascribing the id and field to the appropriate object / element within the object (in this case, content to a blog post). You then need to hide the other text input or it will leave two text boxes for the same element within the object.

Answer (score -1):

Get awesome example from [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/). My example has error because i cannot paste **API KEY** to included external script.

Don't forget that external js library must have format

`https://cloud.tinymce.com/dev/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=qagffr3pkuv17a8on1afax661irst1hbr4e6tbv888sz91jc`

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  theme: 'modern',
  plugins: 'print preview fullpage powerpaste searchreplace autolink directionality advcode visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount tinymcespellchecker a11ychecker imagetools mediaembed  linkchecker contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help',
  toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat',
  image_advtab: true,
  templates: [
    { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
    { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
  ],
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
 });
```

```css
body {
  padding:5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/dev/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: This is not thymeleaf. 

Why does nobody read anything I write on this stupid website.

This is Javascript in HTML. **THIS WILL NOT WORK IN THYMELEAF**!